# How to do multiple mongoDB query by python list automatically

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

Here's my query

```
%%time
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime as dt
mongo_client = MongoClient(...credential...)
db_score = mongo_client['at-device-info']
cvsms = db_score['flat_sms']
test = cvsms.find({'customer_id': {'$in': list1}},{ 'customer_id': 1,'timestamp': 1})
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(test))
```

What I did is copy  last two lines and change `list1` to `list2`, and df1 to `df2`. so it will become

```
test = cvsms.find({'customer_id': {'$in': list2}},{ 'customer_id': 1,'timestamp': 1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(test))
```

Then keep doing the same for `list3` and `df3`. How to do this automatically for 48 list, the one query requires 4 minutes to run on my jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always loop over all your queries and make a DataFrame and add them to a list like so:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

mongo_client = MongoClient(...
credential...)
db_score = mongo_client['at-device-info']
cvsms = db_score['flat_sms']

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5] # list of values to search
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10] # list of values to search
lists = [list1,list2]
df_list = []

for lst in lists:
    test = cvsms.find({'customer_id': {'$in': lst}}, {'customer_id': 1, 'timestamp': 1})
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(test))
    df_list.append(df)


# If you want to access each dataframe seperately from the list you can access the individual list elements
df1 = df_list[0]
df2 = df_list[1]


full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

If you want to speed things up, you could try to use the `concurrent` module with either the `ThreadPoolExecutor` or the `ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
from concurrent import futures

def query_df(lst):
    test = cvsms.find({'customer_id': {'$in': lst}}, {'customer_id': 1, 'timestamp': 1})
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(test))
    return df

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as f:
    df_list = f.map(query_df,lists)

full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

In the end, you can make one big dataframe from the smaller dataframes by concatenating the list.

Comment: will try first :)

Comment: Still confuse to elaborate this with my case, can you make the previous existed list is exist is named `list1`, `list2`... , `list` and the desired output is `df1`, `df2`... , `dfn` ?

Comment: I have 58 python list so
`lists = [list1,list2,...,list58]` and I should type manually?

Comment: Not really, that would be very inefficient. I don't know how you are creating those lists. Hopefully not by hand. You must be reading them off from some place such as a function like `file.read()`. You should have a main list to which you should `append` your small lists to in the function that is creating the lists.